# Evaluate limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (1+\sin{x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: limits

How to evaluate $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (1+\sin{x})^{\frac{1}{x}}?$$
Only idea I can think of is sandwich theorem, but then I get $0^0$.

Comment: Consider two sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ on $(0,\infty)$ that diverges to $\infty$ such that $1+\sin(x_n)=0$ and $1+\sin(y_n)=1$.

Comment: Then by sequential criteria of limits, you can prove that this limit does not exists.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=(1+\sin{x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$.

When $x= 2k \,\pi$ , ($k \in \mathbb{N}$),  $f(x)=1$

When $x= (2k -1/2)\,\pi $ , $f(x)=0$

Hence...

Answer (score 1):

This limit does not exist. We can pick two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $f(a_n)$ has different limit than $f(b_n)$.
\begin{align}
a_n &= 2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2} \\
b_n &= 2\pi n - \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}
Then
$$
\left(1+\sin\left(2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)^{\frac1{2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}}} = 2^{\frac1{2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}}} \rightarrow 1
$$
and
$$
\left(1+\sin\left(2\pi n  - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)^{\frac1{2\pi n  - \frac{\pi}{2}}} = 0^{\frac1{2\pi n - \frac{\pi}{2} }} =0 \rightarrow 0
$$

Answer (score -1):

I went ahead and solved this using Sandwich Theorem but took logarithm first:

Given y = $(1+ sin x)^{1/x}$

Taking logarithm on both sides:

log y = $(1/x) log (1 + sinx)$

We know that $-1< sin x < 1$

0 < $1 + sinx$< 2 (Adding 1 on all sides)

$(log 0)/x < log [1+ sin x]/x < (log 2)/x$  (Taking Log on both sides and dividing by $x$)

Now using LH Rule for computing the $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ $(log 0)/x$ :

We get the limit as 0 after differentiating the numerator and denominator. The numerator being a constant and denominator being differentitaed to 1, gives 0.

Also, $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ $(log 2)/x$ = $0$

Hence $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ $log [1+ sin x]/x$ = $0$ by Sandwich Theorem.

Since $logy$ = $(1/x) log (1 + sinx)$,
from above we have;

$\lim_{x \to \infty}$ $logy$ = $0$

$implies$ $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ $y$ = $e^0$ = $1$

Answer: $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ $(1+ sin x)^{1/x}$ = $1$